# How to accurately query column sizes in PostgreSQL (AWS RDS)

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL DB in AWS RDS. To query how much space each table is taking on disk I do

```
SELECT
  nspname AS schema_name,
  relname AS table_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS size
FROM
  pg_class C
LEFT JOIN
  pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  AND C.relkind = 'r'
ORDER BY
  pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;
```

and the sizes returned are consistent with what I see in AWS RDS monitoring so I trust these numbers. In my case, I have this table called `features_similarity` that is 836 GB

```
 schema_name |            table_name             |  size   
-------------+-----------------------------------+---------
 public      | features_similarity               | 836 GB
```

Note, the schema for this table is as follows

```
postgres=> \d features_similarity
                                  Table "public.features_similarity"
      Column       |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id                | bigint                  |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 user_id           | text                    |           | not null | 
 similarity_type   | text                    |           | not null | 
 similarity_matrix | character varying(40)[] |           |          | 
 work_date         | date                    |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "features_similarity_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "features_similarity_user_id_3cd0a6c6" btree (user_id)
    "features_similarity_user_id_3cd0a6c6_like" btree (user_id text_pattern_ops)
    "single similarity matrix by type" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id, similarity_type, work_date)
```

My problem is that I now want to see how much space each column is taking. The reason is we didn't expect this to take up 836 GB so was trying to debug further. I used this query to estimate size by column:

```
SELECT
  pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(id))) as id_total_size,
  pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(user_id))) as user_id_total_size,
  pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(similarity_type))) as similarity_type_total_size,
  pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(work_date))) as work_date_total_size,
  pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(similarity_matrix))) as similarity_matrix_total_size

FROM
  features_similarity
```

which then returns

```
 id_total_size | user_id_total_size | similarity_type_total_size | work_date_total_size | similarity_matrix_total_size 
---------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------
 1612 kB       | 5037 kB            | 2918 kB                    | 806 kB               | 6793 MB
```

But as you can see the biggest column: `similarity_matrix_total_size` is coming up at under 7 GB. I'm confused how this is consistent with my earlier finding that the table is taking up 836 GB on disk. Again, since I'm also able to monitor on AWS RDS, I can confirm that I believe the 836 GB on disk but I'm not sure how to accurately get the column sizes.

Seems like the problem is that over a certain size the column gets stored in a [toast table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html).

To query Toast Table usage I have

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, row_estimate, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes
 ) AS total
     , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS index
     , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
     , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS table
   FROM (
   SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-coalesce(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
       SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS table_name
               , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
               , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
               , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
               , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
           FROM pg_class c
           LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
           WHERE relkind = 'r'
   ) a
 ) a order by total_bytes desc;
```

which returns

```
    table_schema    |            table_name             | row_estimate |   total    |   index    |   toast    |  table  
--------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+---------
 public             | features_similarity               |       206296 | 836 GB     | 56 MB      | 835 GB     | 120 MB
```

But is there a way to calculate the column size stored in toast?

Comment: Sounds like your table is very bloated.  You could try to assess this using pg_freespace or pgstattuple, but targeting them at the toast table, not the base table.

Comment: Space is not taken up by columns, but by rows. Use the pgstattuple extension to figure out how much bloat you have in your tables and indexes.